# Python: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, string

I have the following code

```
f = open('BigTestFile','w');
str = '0123456789'
for i in range(100000000):
    if i % 1000000 == 0:
        print(str(i / 1000000) + ' % done')
    f.write(str)
f.close()
```

When I run it, I get this `TypeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gen_big_file.py", line 8, in <module>
        print(str(i / 1000000) + ' % done')
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Why is that? How to fix?

Comment: dont use `str` its python internal variable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Call the variable something other than `str`. 
It is shadowing the [`str` built in function.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str)

Answer (score 7):

It's because you overrode the function `str` on line 3.

`str()` is a [builtin function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) in Python which takes care of returning a nice string representation of an object.

Change line 3 from

```
str = '0123456789'
```

to

```
number_string = '0123456789'
```

Comment: I think it's not correct. You may override built-in symbols (though not recommended of course). You can say `str='abc'; print(str)`. The problem here is that he calls it by saying `str()` which is not correct, he must use `[]`

Comment: @JohannesP you didn't understand the problem; limelights answer is correct.

Comment: @JohannesP On line 8 he wants the output to be `1%done`. Changing the string name from `str` to `number_string` will output what OP is asking for even though that in it self will be incorrect and he'll face the problem you're solving to access a strings char by brackets.

Answer (score 2):

You overwrote `str` which is normally a constructor for strings.

You could just change this line to `"{} % done".format(i)` if you really don't want to change it.

Answer (score 0):

And if you insist on overwriting the `str` `class` instantiator with an actual string then replacing `str(i)` with `"".__class__(i)` would fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to access the `i`th element of something, you need to use `[i]` and not `(i)`. And second, as the others already mentioned, *don't* override `str`, the function to obtain any object's string representation.